# custom field - How to get saved term selected for entity_autocomplete

Tags: 8, entities

I've looked all over, and for my level of understanding, I can't figure out how to get the stored value of an entity autocomplete field targeting taxonomy term type. I thought I could do something similar to what I have for select field, but it breaks the page. This is for a custom field...

```
    $element['description_term'] = array(
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      '#selection_settings' => [
        'target_bundles' => [
          'descriptors'
        ],
      ],
      '#title' => t('descriptor'),
      'default_value' => previously-entered-value,
      // this didn't work... '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->descriptor) ? $items[$delta]->descriptor : NULL,
      '#required' => FALSE,
  );
```

Comment: Where is your "description_term" field saved?

Comment: Please forgive...I'm not sure I understand the question? I'm building a custom compound field in Drupal 8. The snippet above is from the Widget php of my custom module.

Comment: Your question is " How to get saved term selected for entity_autocomplete" I am asking where you are saving your field? In taxonomy or any other place?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the field in the database looks like it contains the TID of the taxonomy term. So, I think yes - Taxonomy.

Comment: The to set default value it should be like Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($items[$delta]->description_term->target_id). To provide default value in auto complete you need to pass full entity to it.

Comment: I tried this: $default_value = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($items[$delta]->description_term)->get('name')->value;  ... it does switch out the id for the term, but it's not populating the field, for some reason.

Comment: Any entity reference should be target id not value...

Answer (score 0):

with some help above from Ajay Reddy, I was able to finally get to something that worked... Here's what did it:

> '#default_value' =>
>   \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($items[$delta]->description_term),

Comment: You can also get the associated term entities with $items->referencedEntities()